# k = reduce((lambda x,y,z : abs(x-y) + abs(y-z) + abs(z-x)) , range(List[0]))

Tags: python-3.x

```
k = reduce((lambda x,y,z : abs(x-y) + abs(y-z) + abs(z-x)) , range(List[0]))
```

is giving runtime error.

> error message:- 'TypeError: () missing 1 required positional argument:
>   z'.

What could be the solution for it?

Comment: add your code in the core of the question and not the title. You know that python rely on new line and indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is (most likely, it is a little hard to judge without the rest of the code...) that you're using reduce (which takes a function with two arguments as its first argument) and pass it a function which requires three arguments. reduce then calls your anonymous function with two arguments which results in the exception.

As a side comment: I suggest avoiding the use of capitalized names (such as "List") for your variables. To most python programmers a capitalized name implies that a class.

Answer (score 0):

From `help(reduce)`

```
reduce(...)
    reduce(function, sequence[, initial]) -> value

    Apply a function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of a sequence,
    from left to right, so as to reduce the sequence to a single value.
    For example, reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) calculates
    ((((1+2)+3)+4)+5).  If initial is present, it is placed before the items
    of the sequence in the calculation, and serves as a default when the
    sequence is empty.
```

Seems like reduce passes only 2 parameters at a time and reduces them.